# Show div on second visit

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I want to have the div #topmessage slide down on the users second visit to the site. Also when the user clicks the #close the message will not be shown again. I guess I have to set a cookie and count it but not sure how. I have the following cookie plugin installed together with jquery http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){ 
    $('#topmessage').delay(1000).slideDown(400);
    $("#close").click(function(){
          $("#topmessage").slideToggle(400);
        });

});
</script>
<div id="topmessage">
<a href="#" class="close" id="close">Close</a>
Hi welcome back, if you have any questions please feel free to <a href="/contact">contact me</a>.
</div>
```

**Update**: The reason I want to do this is to push the div to users who have visited the site once and are now returning on another date.  I don’t just want to show the div the second time the site is loaded, but it has to be on another date or session as well. As far as I can see there is no way to access the creation date of a cookie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var value = $.cookie('the_cookie'),
            date = null;
        if (/^\d+$/.test(value || "")) {
             date = new Date();
             date.setTime(value);
        } else if ((value || "") == "") {
             $.cookie('the_cookie', new Date().getTime());
        }

        if (null != date /* && date meets your requirements */){
            $('#topmessage').delay(1000).slideDown(400);
            $("#close").click(function(){
                $("#topmessage").slideToggle(400);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you want to update the date in the cookie at each visit:

```
        if (/^\d+$/.test(value || "")) {
             date = new Date();
             date.setTime(value);
        }
        $.cookie('the_cookie', new Date().getTime());
```

Working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/NL9jd/

UPDATE

added expiration date and path to cookie
added 2nd cookie just for the session

Comment: Thank you - works as advertised. However, I have made an update to the initial question as I needed to be a bit more specific in describing the problem. Thanks

Comment: Now the cookie stores the timestamp.

Comment: For some reason no cookie is set?

Comment: Sorry, now I fixed some bugs and confirmed that it's working (see the demo).

Comment: As soon as the cookie is set and the page is reloaded the div is showing. I am looking to only show the div to the user who has visited the site and who is now returning on another date. Also the close function is only toggling the view not updating the cookie to never show the div again.

Comment: Okay, I think you need a second cookie (just for the session) to make sure the user sees the message only at the next visit (if the permanent cookie exists)... To make that clear, the message should never pop up again only if the user clicks the close link? Will update the demo in a few ...

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much - works just as it should. Tested it out localhost and changed time and date and boom there was the message. Super!

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like this should be stored in the backend and controlled by the server.  The problem with cookies is that someone could delete all of their cookies (or log in via a different browser/computer).  Sounds like a property on a database table relating to the user.

The server could simple set a flag to "show div" and the view could take care of that.  Not sure what sever side technology you are using.

Comment: Even if you do server-side, you would have a cookie for the session. Unless you save user IP address, in which case: 1) not good to do without user consent 2) IP can be dynamic, so you'll loose track anyway. I think cookie is the best way.

Comment: I guess I was assuming that User meant that it was someone who was authenticated.  In that case, you could keep all the data in the database and show links based on things like IsFirstVisit or something like that.  If these are just random users, then yeah, cookies are the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Probably (haven't used Jquery cookie but looking at the doc...) do...

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    if($.cookie("showMessage") == "true") {
    $('#topmessage').delay(1000).slideDown(400);
$.cookie("showMessage","never");
}
else if($.cookie("showMessage") != "never"){
$.cookie("showMessage","true");
}
    $("#close").click(function(){
          $("#topmessage").slideToggle(400);
$.cookie("showMessage","never");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to detect if a cookie exists.
If the cookie exists, then you know the user has already visited once.
If the cookie does not exist, its the first visit, create the cookie.